# How to make excel cell counter go up X amount ever Y number of rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a set of data and I want to filter it so if every 4th row contains a certain word all the above 4 rows are turned into zeros, else it stays the same, for example:

```
1 A <--- turned into zero because the 4th row is x
2 A <--- turned into zero because the 4th row is x
3 A <--- turned into zero because the 4th row is x
4 X <--- turned into zero because the 4th row is x
5 A <--- stays the same because the 4th row is A
6 A <--- stays the same because the 4th row is A
7 A <--- stays the same because the 4th row is A
8 A <--- stays the same because the 4th row is A
```

I'm using the below code but having a hard time making the A4 in the code increase by 4 every 4th row.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A4)),0,A1)
```

the formula should be the following for the above example:

```
1  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A4)),0,A1)
2  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A4)),0,A2)
3  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A4)),0,A3)
4  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A4)),0,A4)
5  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A8)),0,A5)
6  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A8)),0,A6)
7  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A8)),0,A7)
8  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",A8)),0,A8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad, here's something I came up with.  It's a bit lengthy, but it seems to do what you want:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/4,0)*4,1)))),0,A1)
```

This formula is doing the same as what you posted, but calculating the nearest 4th row (rounded up).  This way, you should be able to copy and apply to the whole column